# Finding the eigenvalues of covariance matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Came across this as an interview question that I saw online: given a covariance matrix with diagonals being all 1 and the off-diagonals being c, what are its eigenvalues?

Going by the definition $Av = \lambda v$, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&c&..&c \\ 
c&1&c& ... \\ 
...\\
c&c&...&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\v_2\\...\\v_n
\end{bmatrix} 
=\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\v_2\\...\\v_n
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

then it's easy to get
$$ (c \times(n-1)+1)*v = \lambda * v$$
and thus
$$\lambda = c \times(n-1)+1$$

This is just one eigenvalue. Is there a way to get a solution for all other eigenvalues or is this the best we could do?

Comment: Your matrix $A$ can be written as $A=I + cuu^T$ where $u$ is vector of all ones, which implies that eigenvalues of $A$ are also eigenvalues of  $uu^T$, but $uu^T$ has rank and therefore only one non-zero eigenvalue. So the rest of the eigenvectors of $A$ are the zero eigenvectors of $uu^T$ and therefore the corresponding eigenvalues of $A$ are all 1.

Comment: $A = I +cuu^T$ has diagonals c+1 but the matrix I had in mind has diagonals of just 1. Does that make a difference? Also, could you link explanations to why $A$ and $uu^T$ can share eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Right it should be $A = (1-c)I + cuu^T$. In general $(\alpha I + A)v=\lambda v \Rightarrow Av = (\lambda - \alpha)v$  by basic algebra, namely if $v$ is an eigenvector of $(\alpha I + A)$ then it also an eigenvector of $A$. You should be able to work out the rest of the details from there

Comment: I see. So since $A = (1-c)I + cuu^T$, eigenvalules of A are just eigenvalue of $cuu^T$ plus $\alpha$. So the with zero eigenvectors of $cuu^T$ the corresponding eigenvalues of A is simply  0+ 1 +c = 1+c. Thank you again!